# TSQL Debugging Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I am looking for an effective way to debug complex and lengthy T-Sql.  I have found the MSDN suggestion for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241871%28v=vs.80%29.aspx but when I set the breakpoints it kicks back with "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."  The configuration is setup as debug and not release.  I am running visual studio 2010 professional.

Comment: One option is to use sql profiler.

Comment: A handy technique is to run the code, or fractions thereof, in SSMS after wrapping it in `BEGIN TRANSACTION`/`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.  There may still be side effects, e.g. identity values may be skipped.  That ought not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Management Studio to debug your T-SQL script, unless it involves custom CLR components. Don't use Visual Studio to attach to sqlservr.exe.

Comment: You are powerful enough to mess with sqlservr.exe, and yet you worry about SA rights?

Comment: To mess with Sqlservr.exe?  I was simply following the MSDN posting for attaching a process to it and using the VS debugger; selecting it from a list of process ID's running.  I don't have SA admin rights but still need to debug T-Sql I am building.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a non-optimal suggestion, but one that may be helpful.

Declare an @Debug BIT parameter at the top of the proc, set it to 1, then add in a few

```
IF @Debug = 1
  SELECT 'Debug statement blahblah' //or report something useful for debugging
```

This does alter the proc somewhat but this technique has been useful in the past, especially with lengthy and complicated procs.